# How Xml is created for storyboard?

Tags: ios, xml, storyboard

I know that source code for StoryBoard is created in xml Format and we can check it by right clicking on StoryBoard and open as Source Code. Is it possible to write Source code Manually, if it is  so then, can You Help me out.

Comment: can do but it could be more difficult to make 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mean, you could hand-write the HTML that javascript generates for a website, but that just brings great pain.

Manually writing interface code wouldn't be XML, it would you be defining everything in code (swift or obj c).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean.
If you'd like to edit the Storyboard XML file, as you said, once you right click on StoryBoard and then OpenAs->Source Code, you can not just view it, but also edit it. That's the way you do it.

If you want to **learn** XML programming, it's possible. Many developers don't use the interface builder, they just make their XMLS manually. 
I suggest you start here:

[Introduction to Tree-Based XML Programming Guide for Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSXML_Concepts/NSXML.html)

[Introduction to Event-Driven XML Programming Guide for Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/XMLParsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000186i)

Apple documentation is always the best.